# Difference between type constructors and parametrized type bounds in Scala

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, type-parameter, type-constructor

Take a look at the following code:

```
case class MyTypeConstructor[T[_]: Seq, A](mySeq: T[A]) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): T[B] = mySeq.map(f) // value map is not a member of type parameter T[A]
}

case class MyTypeBounds[T[A] <: Seq[A], A](mySeq: T[A]) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): T[B] = mySeq.map(f) 
}
```

Ideally both would do the same thing, just define a dummy `map` that calls the `map` method from `Seq`. However, the first one does not event compile while the second one works (actually the second one doesen't work either but I am omitting things for simplicity).

The compilation error I get is that `T[A]` does not have a member `map`, but I am stranged because the type constructor `T` should return a `Seq` (which does have `map`).

Can anyone explain me what is conceptually different between these two implementations?

Comment: What you want is a **typeclass** and punctually `Functor` from **cats**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez hahah I know you from Reddit. Thank you for answering again. Yes I know about functors and cats. I actually don't care about this example, I just want to understand the conceptual difference between a type constructor and a type bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is conceptually different between these two implementations?

We can constrain polymorphic type parameters either using subtyping or type class approach

```
scala> case class Subtyping[T[A] <: Seq[A], A](xs: T[A]) {
     |   def map[B](f: A => B) = xs.map(f)
     | }
     | 
     | import scala.collection.BuildFrom
     |
     | case class TypeClassVanilla[T[x] <: IterableOnce[x], A](xs: T[A]) {
     |   def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit bf: BuildFrom[T[A], B, T[B]]): T[B] =
     |     bf.fromSpecific(xs)(xs.iterator.map(f))
     | }
     | 
     | import cats.Functor
     | import cats.syntax.all._
     | 
     | case class TypeClassCats[T[_]: Functor, A](xs: T[A]) {
     |   def map[B](f: A => B): T[B] =
     |     xs.map(f) 
     | }
class Subtyping
import scala.collection.BuildFrom
class TypeClassVanilla
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.all._
class TypeClassCats

scala> val xs = List(1, 2, 3)
val xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Subtyping(xs).map(_ + 1)
val res0: Seq[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala> TypeClassCats(xs).map(_ + 1)
val res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala> TypeClassVanilla(xs).map(_ + 1)
val res2: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

They are different approaches to achieving the same thing. With type class approach perhaps we do not have to worry as much about organising  inheritance hierarchies, which as system grows in complexity, might lead us to start artificially forcing things into hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mario. One thing I’m seeing is why do we associate the T[_] syntax with type classes, the former being a feature of the Scala language and the later a functional programming concept agnostic to the language. What is the difference between the cats example where T[_]: Functor and my example where T[_]: Seq?

Comment: @NicolasSchejtman A key concept to understand is the difference between proper type and type constructor. Sequence is declared something like `trait Seq[A]` meaning type argument `A` needs to be a proper type, whilst functor is declared something like `trait Functor[F[_]]` meaning the type argument `F` needs to be a type constructor. Thus on the syntactic level  `T[_]: Seq` cannot work because type constructor `Seq` expects a proper type but you are trying to provide a type constructor. On the semantic level `T[_]: Seq` makes no sense because `Seq` is not designed to be a type class.

Comment: Great, that answers my question! Thank you a lot Mario 

Answer (score 3):

```
T[_]: Seq
```

This does not say "`T[_]` should return a `Seq`-like this". That's what your second example correctly states. This says "`T[_]` should satisfy an implicit whose name is `Seq`". But `T` takes parameters, so it can't really be a part of an implicit. Essentially, it's trying to do

```
case class MyTypeConstructor[T[_], A](mySeq: T[A])(implicit arg: Seq[T[_]])
```

But `Seq[T[_]]` doesn't make sense as an argument to a function, first off because `T` takes a parameter which is not provided* and second because `Seq` is not intended to be used as an implicit.

We can see that this is an odd construct because you can remove `myMap` and still get an error.

```
// error: type T takes type parameters
case class MyTypeConstructor[T[_]: Seq, A](mySeq: T[A]) {}
```

*Theoretically, the compiler could treat `T[_]: Seq` as a declaration that an implicit existential argument is required, but that isn't what it does now and would be of questionable utility, even if it did.

Comment: "T[_] should satisfy an implicit whose name is Seq" can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo In Scala 2, `T[_]: F` would not be expanded to `implicit ev: F[T[_]]` but `implicit ev: F[T]`. This confusion about the different meaning of underscore `_` at declaration site (anonymous type parameter) and call site (proper existential type) should eventually be [resolved](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html) by Scala 3.